# Pentaho BI-Server JDBC Exception

Tags: pentaho

I'm setting up the pentaho bi-server and I get the following exception when I run start-pentaho.sh:

```
11:45:29,280 ERROR [SchemaUpdate] could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:174)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:165)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
```

I think that I must have missed adding my database username/password and hostname into a configuration file. However, I don't know which of the several pentaho configuration files that I missed updating. From the stacktrace, does anyone have any suggestions about which pentaho file I need to update with my correct db credentials? Thanks.

Update - the three configuration files that I already updated were:

```
pentaho-solutions/system/hibernate/mysql5.hibernate.cfg.xml
pentaho-solutions/system/hibernate/hibernate-settings.xml
pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-jdbc.xml
```

Comment: I'm talking by heart, but it seems you are missing the Pentaho db schemas. Did you create them?

Comment: Yes I did create the db scema, but pentaho has several configuration files and I need to add my db username and password to all of them. I must have missed updating one of them. I'll try to update my post with a list of all the files that I did update.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to update the file "pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-hibernate.properties", but stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question so I'm putting the answer in my comment here.

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out looking for this!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you needed to update the file pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-hibernate.propertie‌​s!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have jdbc libarry in to tomcat/lib ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this can help you but I try http://anonymousbi.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/pentaho-bi-server-4-5-0-definitive-mysql-installation-guide/